# Initialize a string with a char pointer with zero-copy

Tags: c++, string, raii

Say I am given a long and null-terminated cstring as `char* text_ptr`. I own `text_ptr` and I am responsible of `free()`ing it. Currently, I use `text_ptr` and `free()` it each time after use.

I try to improve memory safety a bit by wrapping it in a C++ class so that I can enjoy the benefit of RAII. There could be many ways to achieve it. A naive way is: `string text_ptr(text_ptr);`. However, by doing so, memory is copied once and I still need to manually `free()` my `text_ptr`. It would be better if I can avoid memory copy and `free()` (as this `text_ptr` is created frequently, performance could take a big hit if I copy it each time). My current thought:

Is it possible to transfer the ownership of `text_ptr` to a string `text_str`? Hypothetically, I do `text_str.data() = text_ptr;`.

Thanks

Comment: [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)? [`std::unique_ptr<char>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)? Or considering that you both want a view *and* take over ownership, a simple class that uses a similar interface to `std::string` or `std::string_view` and wraps the string internally in a `std::unique_ptr<char>`?

Comment: Just use `std::string`, but if you want to write your own class use `std::make_unique<char[]>` to manage your memory. 'malloc/free' should not be used in C++, 'new/delete' only inside datastructures. Transfer of ownership will be very clear with a `std::unique_ptr` too. If you want to implement `text_str.data() = text_ptr;.` just copy the string... there is no way to tell from a naked pointer if you can take ownership (and in current C++, the assumption should be naked pointers are non-owning)

Comment: Summary you can't just pickup a raw pointer and assume it is safe to take over ownership.  Just make the copy, because some other code may still have the delete[] call.

Comment: @PepijnKramer the ownership is guaranteed. the function returns me a raw pointer and explicit says I own it.

Comment: Er, you cannot _assign_ to `text_str.data()` — you would simply lose your data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just checked, seems `unique_ptr<char>` fits my need well.

Comment: Must use `unique_ptr<char[]>`, not `<char>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: i just tested it, seems it should be `unique_ptr<char>`, not `unique-ptr<char[]>.

Comment: It depends on which version of the standard you are using. C++17 and later let you say `unique_ptr<char[]>`. Earlier version required `unique_ptr<char>` with an explicit deleter.

Comment: You need to set custom deleter for `std::unique_ptr` for this to work properly. Like `std::unique_ptr<char[], void(*)(void *)> data_;` initializing: `data_{ptr, free};`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Actually, since data was allocated with `malloc` both `delete` and `delete[]` are wrong, but `delete[]` is "more wrong" than `delete`.

Comment: @sklott Mhm, you're right. I don't like storing the function pointer though, I'll make a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` can't receive ownership of an external buffer. The best you can do is `std::unique_ptr`.

By default `std::unique_ptr` will use `delete` (or `delete[]`), but you need `std::free()`, so a custom deleter is required:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

struct FreeDeleter
{
    void operator()(void *p) const
    {
        std::free(p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[], FreeDeleter> ptr((char *)malloc(42));
}
```

If you also store the length, you can construct a temporary `std::string_view` from pointer+length when needed, to conveniently read the string.

---

Or, a oneliner: `std::unique_ptr<char[], std::integral_constant<void(*)(void *), std::free>>`.

Another one for C++20: `std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype([](void *p){std::free(p);})>`.

Comment: My current version is as simple as this: `unique_ptr<char> my_str(get_long_cstr());`. Would it work properly? (I am aware that you provide a deleter, I need some extra time to study what if a deleter is not passed)

Comment: @D.J.Elkind It would cause undefined behavior, because your array expects `free()`, not `delete`. It may or may not work sometimes, but then somebody overrides `new`/`delete` to be incompatible with `malloc`/`free`, and it'll break.

Comment: I see. This is a bit off--my incorrect version `unique_ptr<char> my_str(get_long_cstr());` feels like a drop-in replacement. your correct version is "heavier". I would need to define the `struct FreeDeleter` somewhere, globally, and refer to it each time I need a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: You can define new type, like `using my_string = std::unique_ptr<char[], FreeDeleter>;` with `FreeDeleter` in one place and then just use `my_string` everywhere. Also, see how asan complains when there is no deleter here: https://godbolt.org/z/nbG5s87j9

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Yes, that's the price of correctness. There's also a oneliner version: `std::unique_ptr<char[], std::integral_constant<void(*)(void *), std::free>>`.

Comment: I checked the godbolt link, you enabled `-fsanitize=address` so that the compiler complains. I may need to some to understand what exactly it means...

Comment: for this `std::unique_ptr<char[], std::integral_constant<void(*)(void *), std::free>>`, it makes me think about the way js works (i.e., `()=>free()`), does C++ has something similar (like passing an anonymous function pointer to the 2nd parameter of unique_ptr<>)?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind `std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype([](void *p){std::free(p);})>`, but this requires a fairly modern compiler.

Comment: also, on `std::unique_ptr<char[], deleter>` vs `std::unique_ptr<char, deleter>`? My initial thought is that `unique_ptr<int>` is the "smart" version of `int*`. If this holds, as I am using `char*`, should it be `std::unique_ptr<char, deleter>` instead of `std::unique_ptr<char[], deleter>`?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind `unique_ptr<char>` is supposed to point to a single character, while `unique_ptr<char[]>` is supposed to point to an array. The former lacks e.g. `operator[]`.

Answer (score 0):

An idea (not sure it’s a good one, tho)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

struct my_string_view : public std::string_view
{
  using std::string_view::string_view;
  std::shared_ptr<char[]> _data;
  explicit my_string_view( char * data ) 
    : std::string_view(data)
    , _data{data, free} 
    { }
};

void f( const my_string_view & s )
{
  std::cout << "f: \"" << s << "\"\n";
}

int main()
{
  my_string_view s( strdup( "Hello world!" ) );
  f( s );
  std::cout << "main: \"" << s << "\"\n";
}
```

(This version requires C++17. For older versions of the standard you’ll have to specify the `default_deleter<char[]>()` explicitly.)

Comment: I would use `_data{data, free}` for `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` with corresponding deleter.

Comment: Oops, yep, you're right. Lemme fix that.